# How to handle UserNotification through widget iOS14 to main app in swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, unusernotificationcenter

I have an iOS app with widget iOS 14 where I send `UserNotifications` from both sides. On main app side all `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` is working fine. On widget side when I fetched events from calendar then `UserNotifications` are triggered. When I'm received notification in main-app side and click on it, then `didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse` delegate or other delegates did not called and also did not called in widget side.

**here is my code in Widgets**

```
class NotificationCenter: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var dumbData: UNNotificationResponse?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    }
}
extension NotificationCenter: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate  {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, openSettingsFor notification: UNNotification?) {
        
    }
    func scheduleNotification(at date: Date, identifierUnic : String, body: String, titles:String) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

        let triggerWeekly = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .hour,.minute, .year], from: date)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerWeekly, repeats: true)
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = titles
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.categoryIdentifier = "todoList2"
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifierUnic, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(" We had an error: \(error)")
            }}
    }
}
//and fire in 
@ObservedObject var notificationCenter: NotificationCenter

 func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        eventManager.checkPermission { (eventArray) in
            print(eventArray)
            if eventArray.count > 0{
                for item in eventArray{
                    notificationCenter.scheduleNotification(at: item.startDate ?? Date(), identifierUnic: item.eventIdentifier ?? "", body: item.title, titles: item.title)
                }
            }
        }
        
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate)
            entries.append(entry)
        }
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
```

**On Main App Side**

```
     func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
         let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        print("userInfo \(userInfo)")
}
```

- What is missing in it?
- Is it right way to handle `UserNotification`    on two Targets?
- Any other way to do this?

Please let me know?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar situation that I still can't figure out how to do... I have a widget that will display calendar events. How can I refresh the widget when calendar changed? I tried to use notificationCenter but don't know where to put it. What I want to do is that when there is a calendar change, my widget should be reloaded (refresh timeline.)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: there is no callbacks for new event added but I added some code it refreshes widgets when widget is alive, please check my timeline function.

Comment: for notifications I have found one alternate for this solution, when app is terminate notification fired from widgets, then click on notification on did finish options it saved the user data. you can get notification data from there but not in background state.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. When you said 'some code it refreshes widgets when widget is alive' what do you mean? I see you use policy .atEnd. If  there is a way to refresh widget every time it is alive (i.e. a user is seeing it) that would have. But the best is to be able to reload timelines when calendar changed. I will get back to you should I know how to do this. Still researching...

Comment: yes I saw it is not proper reloading when we not in debug mood. yes we need to find some other solutions

Comment: I will get back to you should I know how to do this. Still researching... --- I'm waiting for your best answer, thank you for helping me